# Determining stability of Equibrium of a Centre

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, polar-coordinates, differential, jacobian

Given the system:

$\dot x$ = $y$, $\dot y$ = $\epsilon x^3 - x$,

equilibria points are (0,0), $(\frac{1}{\sqrt \epsilon}, 0) $, $(-\frac{1}{\sqrt \epsilon}, 0) $

Thus, the jacobian matrix is:

$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
3\epsilon x^2 - 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

At the origin (0,0)

$$ J = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 \\
- 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} $$

This is
a degenerate case, i.e. a centre, so how can you determine the stability of this equilibrium point by converting to polar coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

This system has a first integral
$$
V(x,y)=y^2+x^2-\fracϵ2x^4.
$$
This leads to concentric closed level curves around $(0,0)$, and the solutions of the system follow these curves.